# Cell Content (Textview) only Update after touching the cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextview

i created a UITableViewCell with a UITextView inside. 
I´m using Json to get my Html Content for the Textview. I´m using DTCoreText also. Here  a part of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"NewsCell";

GTNewsCustomCell *newsCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

if(newsCell == nil){

    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GTNewsCustomCell"
                                                      owner:self//transfer ownership to self
                                                    options:nil];
    newsCell = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
}

newsCell.cellFrame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300,40);

newsCell.titleLabel.text = [[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"title"];

newsCell.messageTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
newsCell.messageTextView.backgroundColor = GTDefaultTextBackgroundColor;
newsCell.messageTextView.editable = NO;
newsCell.messageTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

newsCell.messageTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

NSString *htmlTag = @"<b></b>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",htmlTag,[[self.newsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"previewMessage"]];


.
.
.

return newsCell;
```

The Problem is that the Content of my TextView is sometimes bigger than the textview size. The strange thing is when i touch the textview, it updates himself and everybody is shown correct....what could be wrong?

Here are some Screenshots:

Broken TextView:
[image]

When i touch the Cell, the Text is formatted:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Ok no i have found my Problem but i dont know how to solve it. In my Custom Cell .m File i have a method for change the cell size width:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   CGRect cellRect = self.bounds;
   cellRect.size.width = self.cellFrame.size.width;

   self.bounds = cellRect; 
}
```

If i delete this everything works fine, BUT of course my cell have not the correct size anymore...but i need some space from the left and from the right between the TableView and the Cell!

Comment: Can you reduce the issue some, as in, find a minimal amount of code the reproduce the issue?

Comment: I hope its better know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally i solved the issue: I delete the "layoutSubviews" Method, and insert:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += 10;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * 10;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Now my Text always have the correct Size and my Cell have also the correct Size!

Answer (score 0):

I always think it's best not to try to tamper with the frame/bounds of a `UITableViewCell`. Each cell's frame is set by the `UITableView`, with width equal to the table view's width, and height equal to either the value returned by the table view delegate's `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, or if that's not implemented, the table view's `rowHeight` property.

If your custom cell's contents, i.e. subviews, are not where you want them, then position and size *these* in your custom `layoutSubviews` implementation (or in your nib). Auto layout can be an option here. In your example, you would lay out the cell's `messageTextView`.